# Did they remove Sprite sorting layers from Unity?

Tags: unity, sprites, sorting

I can't figure out how to set it. I thought it was a setting on the sprite renderer but it doesn't seem to be there? Google isn't turning up any results.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top right of the inspector right next to the little lock icon -> select normal. You should now see the sorting layers and order.

Comment: *explodes into a red mist*

Comment: huh ? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @dave Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue :)